# Can't display in console log a Angular object value with controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console

I'm beginner in AngularJS and so I try to learn this framework.
To train, I use a REST API with Star Wars data (https://swapi.co/).
I have a problem : i can't display a value of object in console log.

See my Angular JS code :

```
var pokeApp = angular.module('pokedex', ['ngResource']);

pokeApp.config(['$resourceProvider', function($resourceProvider) {
    $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
}]);

pokeApp.controller('PokeController', function ($scope,$log, People) {
$scope.people = null;
$scope.getPeople = function(idPeople) {
    $myPeople = People.get({id:idPeople});
    $log.log($myPeople.name); // result in console : undefined
    $scope.people = $myPeople;
    $log.log($scope.people.name); // result in console : undefined  
};
}); 

pokeApp.service('People', function($resource)
{
  $jsonPeople =  $resource('https://swapi.co/api/people/:id', {id:'@id'});
  return $jsonPeople;
});
```

And see my HTML code :

```
   <body ng-app="pokedex">
       <div class="container" ng-controller="PokeController">
           <h1>Star Wars Engine</h1>

           <div>
               <input ng-model="idPeople"/>
              <button ng-click="getPeople(idPeople)">Search</button>
           </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <table border="1" class="tableSW">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Sexe</th>
                    <th>Taille</th>
                    <th>Poids</th>
                    <th>Date de naissance</th>
                    <th>Couleur de peau</th>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ people.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ people.gender }}</td>
                    <td>{{ people.height }}</td>
                    <td>{{ people.mass }}</td>
                    <td>{{ people.birth_year }}</td>
                    <td>{{ people.skin_color }}</td>                     
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/pokedex.js"></script>

    <style>
        .tableSW td{
            width: 150px;
        }
        .tableSW th{
            width: 150px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

When i try to display value of my object from API in the console, it contains "undefined".

I don't understand why, can you explain me ?
I specify the display of informations in the view works very well.

Thanks a lot.

Simon.

Comment: Hi any matches if you just log $log.log($myPeople); ?

Comment: yes, it works with $log.log($myPeople)... I can see in console all informations of object.

Comment: Paste the object to drive you how to acces to them attributes.

Comment: {
  "name": "Luke Skywalker",
  "height": "172",
  "mass": "77",
  "hair_color": "blond",
  "skin_color": "fair",
  "eye_color": "blue",
  "birth_year": "19BBY",
  "gender": "male",
  "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
  "species": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"
  ],
  "vehicles": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"
  ],
  "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
  "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
  "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
}

Comment: The $ prefix on services in AngularJS is intended to indicate it's a built-in service or function. It's inadvisable to use $ as a prefix on your own services, variables or functions.

Comment: What result you got if you try to access like this : <code>$log.log($myPeople[0].name);</code>?

Comment: With $log.log($myPeople[0].name) : JS crash and I have an error in console log : TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at b.$scope.getPeople (pokedex.js:11)
    at angular.js:12404
    at f (angular.js:21566)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:14466)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:14565)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21571)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11655

Comment: @JCFord : So, how I can use my variable ? In my context, how i can get the attribute value of my object ?

Answer (score 0):

For information, I can display the json of the object in the console ($log.log($myPeople)) :

```
{
  "name": "Luke Skywalker",
  "height": "172",
  "mass": "77",
  "hair_color": "blond",
  "skin_color": "fair",
  "eye_color": "blue",
  "birth_year": "19BBY",
  "gender": "male",
  "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
  "films": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
  ],
  "species": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"
  ],
  "vehicles": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"
  ],
  "starships": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/12/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/22/"
  ],
  "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
  "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
  "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
}
```

But, it's impossible to display the name of other attribute of this object ...
$log.log($myPeople.name) returns "undefined" in console

Answer (score 0):

The $resource service performs an asynchronous HTTP call. It doesn't return your data right away, instead it returns an empty object. A callback function should be passed as the second argument and it will be called when your data is available. Something like this should work.

```
$scope.getPeople = function(idPeople) {
    $myPeople = People.get({id:idPeople}, function() {
        $log.log($myPeople.name); // result in console : undefined
        $scope.people = $myPeople;
        $log.log($scope.people.name); // result in console : undefined  
    });
};
```

You should review the documentation on $resource on the angularjs website.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource